# how to display bar graph using stack

Tags: flot

My bar graph is not stacking plus its also display extra 2 bars

```js
var datasets = [{"label":"Amend Existing Report","data":[{"0":-61666272000000,"1":2},{"0":-61665667200000,"1":6},{"0":-61665062400000,"1":1},{"0":-61664457600000,"1":1},{"0":-61663852800000,"1":1},{"0":-61663248000000,"1":3},{"0":-61662643200000,"1":1},{"0":-61661433600000,"1":2},{"0":-61660828800000,"1":7},{"0":-61660224000000,"1":3},{"0":-61659619200000,"1":4},{"0":-61659014400000,"1":4}],"idx":0},{"label":"Investigate Report Problem","data":[{"0":-61659014400000,"1":1}],"idx":1},{"label":"New Request (One Off Report)","data":[{"0":-61666876800000,"1":4},{"0":-61666272000000,"1":19},{"0":-61665667200000,"1":7},{"0":-61665062400000,"1":5},{"0":-61664457600000,"1":2},{"0":-61663852800000,"1":3},{"0":-61662038400000,"1":8},{"0":-61661433600000,"1":2},{"0":-61660828800000,"1":8},{"0":-61660224000000,"1":6},{"0":-61659619200000,"1":4},{"0":-61659014400000,"1":5}],"idx":2},{"label":"New Request (Regular Report)","data":[{"0":-61666272000000,"1":4},{"0":-61665667200000,"1":2},{"0":-61665062400000,"1":3},{"0":-61664457600000,"1":1},{"0":-61662038400000,"1":1},{"0":-61660828800000,"1":2},{"0":-61659619200000,"1":2},{"0":-61659014400000,"1":1}],"idx":3},{"label":"Other","data":[{"0":-61665667200000,"1":1},{"0":-61665062400000,"1":1},{"0":-61664457600000,"1":4},{"0":-61663852800000,"1":1},{"0":-61660224000000,"1":2}],"idx":4},{"label":"Special Events","data":[{"0":-61666272000000,"1":1}],"idx":5}];

var options = {"legend":{"position":"ne","noColumns":6},"yaxis":{"min":0},"xaxis":{"mode":"time","timeformat":"%d %b"},"grid":{"clickable":true,"hoverable":true},"series":{"stack":true,"bars":{"show":true,"barWidth":181440000.00000003,"align":"center"}}};

$.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codicode/flotanimator/master/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>

<div id = "choices_CAGraph">

</div>
<div id="CAGraph" style="width:910px;height:400px">
```

How can i add `0` for undefined as mentioned in below answer

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var val = parseInt(data[i].COUNT);
        var to_seconds = moment(data[i].TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD').unix() * 1000;
        if (typeof arr[data[i][id]] == 'undefined' && !(arr[data[i][id]] instanceof Array) ) {
            arr[data[i][id]] = [];
        }
        if (typeof arr[data[i][id]][to_seconds] == 'undefined' && !(arr[data[i][id]][to_seconds] instanceof Array)) {
            arr[data[i][id]][to_seconds] = [];
        }

        old_value = arr[data[i][id]][to_seconds];
        arr[data[i][id]][to_seconds] = null;
        if (typeof old_value === "object") // required for 0 values
            old_value = 0;

        arr[data[i][id]][to_seconds] = (parseInt(old_value) + val);     
    }
```

`data` consists of records, which have timestamp, id, and value. some ids may not all have timestamp. this is coming from db.

Comment: Please do not change the question after it was answered. Ask a new question instead (and link to the previous question if it is relevant). Each question should be about one specific issue (see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300969/2610249) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188627/235872)) and should have an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the stacking to work, all data series must have a y-value for every x-value (timestamp). Use zero if no data is available. Otherwise flot calculates the top and bottom values for the stacks chart with something like `bar3bottom = 2 + 4 + undefined = undefined`and then the bar starts at zero.

You can add the zero values to your data series on the server-side or with some JavaScript loops. See the updated code snippet below for that.

```js
var datasets = [{
  "label": "Amend Existing Report",
  "data": [{
    "0": -61666876800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": -61666272000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": -61665667200000,
    "1": 6
  }, {
    "0": -61665062400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61664457600000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61663852800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61663248000000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": -61662643200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61661433600000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": -61660828800000,
    "1": 7
  }, {
    "0": -61660224000000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": -61659619200000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": -61659014400000,
    "1": 4
  }],
  "idx": 0
}, {
  "label": "Investigate Report Problem",
  "data": [{
    "0": -61666876800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": -61659014400000,
    "1": 1
  }],
  "idx": 1
}, {
  "label": "New Request (One Off Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": -61666876800000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": -61666272000000,
    "1": 19
  }, {
    "0": -61665667200000,
    "1": 7
  }, {
    "0": -61665062400000,
    "1": 5
  }, {
    "0": -61664457600000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": -61663852800000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": -61662038400000,
    "1": 8
  }, {
    "0": -61661433600000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": -61660828800000,
    "1": 8
  }, {
    "0": -61660224000000,
    "1": 6
  }, {
    "0": -61659619200000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": -61659014400000,
    "1": 5
  }],
  "idx": 2
}, {
  "label": "New Request (Regular Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": -61666272000000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": -61665667200000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": -61665062400000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": -61664457600000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61662038400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61660828800000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": -61659619200000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": -61659014400000,
    "1": 1
  }],
  "idx": 3
}, {
  "label": "Other",
  "data": [{
    "0": -61665667200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61665062400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61664457600000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": -61663852800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": -61660224000000,
    "1": 2
  }],
  "idx": 4
}, {
  "label": "Special Events",
  "data": [{
    "0": -61666272000000,
    "1": 1
  }],
  "idx": 5
}];

var options = {
  "legend": {
    "position": "ne",
    "noColumns": 6
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "min": 0
  },
  "xaxis": {
    "mode": "time",
    "timeformat": "%d %b"
  },
  "grid": {
    "clickable": true,
    "hoverable": true
  },
  "series": {
    "stack": true,
    "bars": {
      "show": true,
      "barWidth": 181440000.00000003,
      "align": "center"
    }
  }
};

var allXvalues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < datasets[i].data.length; j++) {
    if (allXvalues.indexOf(datasets[i].data[j][0]) < 0) {
      allXvalues.push(datasets[i].data[j][0]);
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < allXvalues.length; j++) {
    var datasetHasXvalue = false;

    for (var k = 0; k < datasets[i].data.length; k++) {
      if (datasets[i].data[k][0] == allXvalues[j]) {
        datasetHasXvalue = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!datasetHasXvalue) {
      datasets[i].data.push([allXvalues[j], 0]);
    }
  }
  datasets[i].data.sort(dataSort);
}

function dataSort(d1, d2) {
  return d2[0] - d1[0];
}

var plot = $.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codicode/flotanimator/master/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>

<div id="choices_CAGraph"></div>
<div id="CAGraph" style="width:910px;height:400px">
```

Comment: the graph should show 13 weeks as i have taken last 13 weeks from db so how can i line up the bars with the correct week and show 13 bars and not 14?

Comment: Your data has 14 different timestamps, so there are 14 weeks. Maybe a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error)?

Comment: I have updated my code snippet to show 13 bars of 13 timestamps but the x labels are showing only 12 dates and do not line up.

Comment: it seems to me the xaxis time always starts on sunday. any way to change this to a Monday?